# Docker compose before script download file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to download a file (like db.sql) from a remote server before `docker-compose start`?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no [pre/post command option](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/468). I suppose you will have to do this programmatically or with a script. See this similar question: [docker-compose - database migrations and other pre/post scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715239/docker-compose-database-migrations-and-other-pre-post-scripts)

Comment: Is possible to do `ADD wget ...` in the Dockerfile what you reffers in docker-compose.yml `build:` section, but there's no post command option in docker-compose.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to make a shell script.